# Laravel instead sending mail, save it in gmail draft with all ready to hit send button

Tags: php, laravel, gmail

I have mail system working in laravel, the below code sends mail,

```
Mail::to($to)->send(new PendingEvaluationMailtoClient($pendingdeposits, $variance, $subject, $text));
```

What i want is, do not send mail, i want it in gmail draft, so that later i can manually hit `send` button to send mail (we need to verify something manually).

Is it possible in laravel?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel Mail doesn't have this type of ability.

You must use [Gmail Drafts API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts).